# Gem to track user activity in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a gem which should able track all user activities in detail without any manual work. It should work just by adding Include/require in models/controllers etc. Which should support rails 2.3.4 and ruby 1.9.3. Ex. like John created document with name XYZ 2 minutes ego. etc

Comment: "without any manual work" I don't think that exists.

Comment: The hints in these Railscasts on [Public Activity](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) and [Creating an Activity Feed from Scratch (Pro)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch) can help.

Comment: @Mischa https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails#setup this is not really far from 'no manual work' :)

Comment: It really depends on how you want to show these activities. Will you show to the people which follow said person, will you just want to have an organization overview (more like an audit log?). If it's an audit log use paper trail, if you're building a newsfeed use stream_rails.

Answer (score 4):

Look for either [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) or [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to have a look at getstream.io and the stream_rails gem; getstream allows you to build full featured news feeds and activity feeds in almost no time.

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of getstream.io and the author of the ruby gem.